# Angular api service with BehaviorSubject do not refresh components data in realtime

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I created a CRUD service that makes calls to a classic API. I use the behaviorsubject to share data across all components of my application. The problem is that when I perform crud operations, data do not update in all components in real time. The data will update if I navigate in another components.

I do not understand why it does not work in real time and I can't find where my mistake comes from.

If anyone can help me that would be very nice :)

I tried to call the get Candidates () function that updates the datastore with the next () function in each ngOnInit () of my components but the behavior is the same

github repo : https://github.com/jbty/signalr-majority-vote/tree/master/signalR-majority-vote/ClientApp

api angular service :

```js
export class ApiCandidateService {
  public candidatesList: Observable<Candidate[]>;
  private baseUrl: string;
  private _candidatesList: BehaviorSubject<Candidate[]>;
  private dataStore: {
    candidatesList: Candidate[];
  };
  private httpOptions: { headers: HttpHeaders } = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      "Content-Types": "applications/json"
    })
  };

  public constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.baseUrl = "api/Candidates";
    this.dataStore = { candidatesList: [] };
    this._candidatesList = <BehaviorSubject<Candidate[]>>new BehaviorSubject([]);
    this.candidatesList = this._candidatesList.asObservable();
  }

  public getCandidates() {
    this.http.get<Candidate[]>(this.baseUrl, this.httpOptions).subscribe(
      (data: Candidate[]) => {
        this.dataStore.candidatesList = data;
        this._candidatesList.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).candidatesList);
      },
      error => {
        this.handleError(error);
      }
    );
  }

  public getCandidate(id: number | string) {
    this.http.get<Candidate>(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`, this.httpOptions).subscribe(
      (data: Candidate)  => {
        let notFound = true;

        this.dataStore.candidatesList.forEach((item, index) => {
          if (item.candidateId == data.candidateId) {
            this.dataStore.candidatesList[index] = data;
            notFound = false;
          }
        });

        if (notFound) {
          this.dataStore.candidatesList.push(data);
        }

        this._candidatesList.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).candidatesList);
      },
      error => {
        this.handleError(error);
      }
    );
  }

  public createCandidate(newCandidate: Candidate) {
    this.http.post<Candidate>(`${this.baseUrl}`, newCandidate, this.httpOptions).subscribe(
      (data: Candidate) => {
        this.dataStore.candidatesList.push(data);
        this._candidatesList.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).candidatesList);
      },
      error => {
        this.handleError(error);
      }
    );
  }

  public updateCandidate(id: number | string, updatedCandidate: Candidate) {
    this.http.put<Candidate>(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`, updatedCandidate, this.httpOptions).subscribe(
      () => {
        this.dataStore.candidatesList.forEach((candidate, i) => {
          if (candidate.candidateId == updatedCandidate.candidateId) {
            this.dataStore.candidatesList[i] = updatedCandidate;
          }
        });

        this._candidatesList.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).candidatesList);
      },
      error => {
        this.handleError(error);
      }
    );
  }

  public deleteCandidate(id: number | string) {
    this.http.delete<Candidate>(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`, this.httpOptions).subscribe(
      response => {
        this.dataStore.candidatesList.forEach((candidate, i) => {
          if (candidate.candidateId == Number(id)) {
            this.dataStore.candidatesList.splice(i, 1);
          }
        });

        this._candidatesList.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).candidatesList);
      },
      error => {
        this.handleError(error);
      }
    );
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error("An error occurred:", error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(`Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` + `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError("Something bad happened; please try again later.");
  }
}
```

example component

```js
export class DeleteCandidatesComponent implements OnInit {
  public candidate: Observable<Candidate>;
  public candidateId: string;

  constructor(
    public nav: NavigationService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private candidateService: ApiCandidateService
  ) {
    this.candidateId = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.candidate = this.candidateService.candidatesList.pipe(
      map(candidate => candidate.find(item => item.candidateId == Number(this.candidateId)))
    );

    this.candidateService.getCandidate(this.candidateId);
  }

  public onDefinitivlyDeleteCandidate(id: string) {
    this.candidateService.deleteCandidate(id);
    this.nav.outletsNav('classement', 'manage/candidates')
  }
}
```

my view

```html
<header>
  <h2>
    êtes vous sûr de vouloir supprimer définitvement
    <strong>{{ (candidate | async)?.firstName }} {{ (candidate | async)?.lastName }}</strong> ?
  </h2>
</header>
<aside class="submit">
  <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="onDefinitivlyDeleteCandidate(candidateId)">
    Oui
  </button>
  <button mat-button color="warn" (click)="nav.outletsNav('classement', 'manage/candidates')">
    annuler
  </button>
</aside>
```

Comment: What is the reason of keeping local cache if you are still going first to your server than working with cache?

Comment: Have you tried using directly `_candidatesList` in the component instead of `candidatesList` from the service?

Answer (score 0):

> UPDATE

```
export class ApiCandidateService {

  private baseUrl: string;
  private dataStore: {
    candidatesList: Candidate[];
  };
  private _store = new BehaviourSubject<Candidate []>(dataStore);
  public state$: this._store.asObservable();
  public candidatesList$

  private httpOptions: { headers: HttpHeaders } = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      "Content-Types": "applications/json"
    })
  };

  public constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.baseUrl = "api/Candidates";

    this.candidatesList$ = this.state$.pipe(map(state => 
                            state.candidatesList), 
                            distinctUntilChanged());

  }

  public getCandidates() {
    this.http.get<Candidate[]>(this.baseUrl, this.httpOptions).subscribe(
      (data: Candidate[]) => {
        this.dataStore.candidatesList = data;
        this._store.next(Object.assign({}, 
           this.dataStore).candidatesList);
      },
      error => {
        this.handleError(error);
      }
    );
  }

  public getCandidate(id: number | string) {
    this.http.get<Candidate>(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`, this.httpOptions).subscribe(
      (data: Candidate)  => {
        let notFound = true;

        this.dataStore.candidatesList.forEach((item, index) => {
          if (item.candidateId == data.candidateId) {
            this.dataStore.candidatesList[index] = data;
            notFound = false;
          }
        });

        if (notFound) {
          this.dataStore.candidatesList.push(data);
        }

        this._store.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).candidatesList);
      },
      error => {
        this.handleError(error);
      }
    );
  }

  public createCandidate(newCandidate: Candidate) {
    this.http.post<Candidate>(`${this.baseUrl}`, newCandidate, this.httpOptions).subscribe(
      (data: Candidate) => {
        this.dataStore.candidatesList.push(data);
        this._store.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).candidatesList);
      },
      error => {
        this.handleError(error);
      }
    );
  }

  public updateCandidate(id: number | string, updatedCandidate: Candidate) {
    this.http.put<Candidate>(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`, updatedCandidate, this.httpOptions).subscribe(
      () => {
        this.dataStore.candidatesList.forEach((candidate, i) => {
          if (candidate.candidateId == updatedCandidate.candidateId) {
            this.dataStore.candidatesList[i] = updatedCandidate;
          }
        });

        this._store.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).candidatesList);
      },
      error => {
        this.handleError(error);
      }
    );
  }

  public deleteCandidate(id: number | string) {
    this.http.delete<Candidate>(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`, this.httpOptions).subscribe(
      response => {
        this.dataStore.candidatesList.forEach((candidate, i) => {
          if (candidate.candidateId == Number(id)) {
            this.dataStore.candidatesList.splice(i, 1);
          }
        });

        this._store.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).candidatesList);
      },
      error => {
        this.handleError(error);
      }
    );
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error("An error occurred:", error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(`Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` + `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError("Something bad happened; please try again later.");
  }
}
```

> In the view component

```
 export class DeleteCandidatesComponent implements OnInit {
  public candidate: Observable<Candidate>;
  public candidateId: string;

  constructor(
    public nav: NavigationService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private candidateService: ApiCandidateService
  ) {
    this.candidateId = this.route.snapshot.params.id;

**this.candidate$ = this.candidateService.candidatesList$.pipe(
      map(candidate => candidate.find(item => item.candidateId == Number(this.candidateId)))
    );**
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {


    this.candidateService.getCandidate(this.candidateId);
  }

  public onDefinitivlyDeleteCandidate(id: string) {
    this.candidateService.deleteCandidate(id);
    this.nav.outletsNav('classement', 'manage/candidates')
  }
}
```

> In the template

```
{{ (candidate$ | async)?.firstName }} {{ (candidate$ | 
             async)?.lastName }}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! I tried your solution but it's doesn't work, 
nothing changes :(

Comment: There is an another option you can try in your template, use ( | async ) 
Sample code : 
(sampleObservable$ | async) 
This will auto subscribe the data when some updated data available.

Comment: I already work with async pipe. my component view : {{ (candidate | async)?.firstName }} {{ (candidate | async)?.lastName }}

Comment: You're getting the value directly from service 'candidatesList', but you suppose to get it from 'dataStore' state object.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating your property in `ngOnInit()`, which will be called only when you navigate to that view and hence only updates when you navigate to that component.

You can make a get function to get that value and update it in the view.

component:

```
 export class DeleteCandidatesComponent implements OnInit {
  public candidate: Observable<Candidate>;
  public candidateId: string;

  constructor(
    public nav: NavigationService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private candidateService: ApiCandidateService
  ) {
    this.candidateId = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {}

  public onDefinitivlyDeleteCandidate(id: string) {
    this.candidateService.deleteCandidate(id);
    this.nav.outletsNav('classement', 'manage/candidates')
  }

  get getCandidates():  Observable<Candidate>{
     this.candidate = this.candidateService.candidatesList.pipe(
      map(candidate => candidate.find(item => item.candidateId == 
       Number(this.candidateId)))
    );
    this.candidateService.getCandidate(this.candidateId);
    return this.candidate;
  }

}
```

view:

```
<header>
  <h2>
    êtes vous sûr de vouloir supprimer définitvement
    <strong>{{ (getCandidates)?.firstName }} {{ (getCandidates)?.lastName }}</strong> ?
  </h2>
</header>
<aside class="submit">
  <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="onDefinitivlyDeleteCandidate(candidateId)">
    Oui
  </button>
  <button mat-button color="warn" (click)="nav.outletsNav('classement', 'manage/candidates')">
    annuler
  </button>
</aside>
```

Comment: Thank your for tour reply, it's not working, normally with observables and behaviorsubject all views will be refresh automatically in realtime without need to navigate